# Why do series like Detective Conan continue to produce filler when they have so much manga content to cover?

Tags: anime-production, detective-conan

I was just wondering why anime series, Conan in particular, continually produce TV Original and, In Conan's case, Remastered episodes, when they have a couple of whole volumes of manga sitting around, waiting to get adapted.

Conan has Volumes 89-90, and most of 91, completed, and yet they churn out TV Original and Remastered episodes frequently.

http://www.detectiveconanworld.com/wiki/Volume_81-90

In the current season alone they had a string of up to 16 weeks of TV Original and Remastered episodes.

http://www.detectiveconanworld.com/wiki/Season_25

Comment: That's like asking why certain series only do 25ep seasons when there are hundreds of manga chapters. Or why most anime are way more fan-servicey than the manga. It's the industry, popular trends, marketing and the money making scheme. But I'll leave that as a comment

Comment: Why would Naruto continue with fillers even after using up the manga content that the author has stated is the end.. Oh wait, that is another question. :/

Answer (score 1):

The period between manga and filler is always kept as about one year. For example, vol 99 is in April 2021, and the corresponding fill of vol 98 ended at the beginning of 2022.

The production time of one episode is about three months and some stories need more than one episode, so the period is necessary.

Also, the time flag such as the seasons and festivals of manga is close to real-world time. To make the time of filler also close to the real world. At least one year is necessary.